# Error de conexión userId (f8s2WZzXiiS45WJHyj/A4T==): Length is not valid

Tags: java, genexus, genexus15

Tengo un error que se presenta de manera recurrente.  Se me ha presentado en gx15, gx16 y gx17.  Trabajo un una kb normalmente hasta que presenta este error.  La única forma de solucionarlo que he encontrado hasta ahora es volver a crear un `Environment`.  No se si alguien tenga alguna idea de como solucionarlo.

> Caused by: com.ibm.as400.access.ExtendedIllegalArgumentException: userId (f8s2WZzXiiS45WJHyj/A4T==): Length is not valid.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Suena a un problema interno del software que usas para correr genexus. Ese userId seguro se genera internamente y, extrañamente, no logra usarlo él mismo como argumento. Algún lío de versiones de librerías, versiones soportadas del software base, tal vez?